# How to temporarily store data in application memory ,so that it does not get saved when the application is restarted in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Can any one help me to save data in application memory so that their is no data saved when app is restarted and the stored data needs to be used internally among pages .

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android) to store your data when you want to use.And remove it when you don't need it.

```
Preferences.Set("my_key", "my_value"); //save data

var myValue = Preferences.Get("my_key", "default_value"); //get data

Preferences.Remove("my_key"); //remove the key from preferences:

Preferences.Clear(); // remove all preferences
```

Or [Secure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android).

```
await SecureStorage.SetAsync("oauth_token", "secret-oauth-token-value");//save the data

var oauthToken = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("oauth_token"); //get the data

SecureStorage.Remove("oauth_token");  //remove a specific key

SecureStorage.RemoveAll();  //remove all keys
```

Comment: is it good approach  for uses case like Master Password that need not to be saved in disk but still it used inside app for encryption and decryption ?

Comment: if you want to store the cipher key used to encrypt the value,you could use [Xamarin.Essentials: Secure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android).